# Unable to delete Snapshot from Snapshot Manager in Virtual machine

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware

I have a `Virtual Machine` with many snaps.
When I am going to delete any of the snap from the snapshot manager it shows error as `The Virtual machine is a Template` and does not allow me too delete the snap.

Can any one tell me why this has been happened?

There is also one problem, in Snapshot manager if we check the checkbox for the **Show AutoProtect Snapshots** it shows too many hidden shapshots.

How I can delete those Snapshots?

any type of suggestion or help can be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I happened to stumble over this issue today and tried to head over the VMware KB article but the page is not there.
Updating the original question in case someone encounters this same issue.

Presuming the VM in question is already shutdown when you try to delete the snapshot from snapshot manager. Go over and open up the VMX file of the VM in your editor and remove the line which says    `templateVM="true"` . Save the file.

Answer (score 0):

The following kb should assist you in changing from a template vm http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1004538

Comment: The page is gone. What was the advice on that page?